# Is there a way to block commands in a Telegrambot for a certain time?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

Me and my group are currently programming a telegrambot (in python) and want it to play various games with you on demand. For example, a game should be executed with the command `/game1`. If the game process is active, only the commands for the game should be possible, as well as an `/exit` and a `/help`. Is there a way to program a Telegram bot in Python to block certain commands when executing a method?

Assuming the commands for the game number 1 are: `/command1` and `/command2` and for the game number 2: `/command3` and `/command4`. If I now play the first game with `/game1`, it should not be possible to execute `/command3` and `/command4` until I end the current game with `/exit` and activate the second game with `/game2`.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a dictionary mapping the game with the list of allowed commands for that game and then check whether the command is contained in that list.
One way to go could be

```
def is_command_allowed(game, command):
    game_commands = {
        'game1': ['command1', 'command2'],
        'game2': ['command3', 'command4'],
    }

    return command in game_commands[game]


# READ INPUT i.e. game and command (here hardcoded)

# EXAMPLE 1
game = 'game1'
command = 'command3'

is_command_allowed(game, command) # False

# EXAMPLE 2
game = 'game2'
command = 'command4'

is_command_allowed(game, command) # True
```